# Dúvida teórica sobre while e indentação

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
count = 0
while (count < 10):
    # Ponto A
    print ("Olá...", count)
    count =  count + 1
    # Ponto B
# Ponto C
```

Por que

> count < 10 é sempre true no ponto B.

não é verdadeiro se o "Ponto B" pertence a mesma indentação do "Ponto A" dentro do while?

Outra pergunta:

```
i = 6
while (i > 0):
    i = i - 3
    print (i)
```

Por que a saída é 3 e 0 e não somente 3?

Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vc perguntou por que no código abaixo:

```
(1) i = 6
(2) while (i > 0):
(3)   i = i - 3;
(4)   print (i)
```

A saída é 3 e 0 e não somente 3. A resposta é simples, mas requer que você considere como o Python interpreta cada linha de comando. Pra facilitar, eu enumerei as linhas no código acima, ok?

A primeira linha executada é (1). Ela simplesmente atribui o valor 6 à variável i. A segunda linha executada é (2). Ela verifica se i > 0, e como i vale 6 (neste momento), isso é verdadeiro e o Python permite que a execução entre no laço. Assim, a próxima linha executada é (3), que faz com que i receba i - 3. Como nesse momento i vale 6, o resultado é i = 6 - 3, logo i = 3. Esse valor é o impresso na próxima linha, como esperado.

A execução então retorna à linha (2). O valor atual de i é 3 (que aliás, foi o último impresso). Como i > 0 (porque 3 > 0) é verdadeiro, o processamento entra novamente no laço. A linha (3) faz a subtração novamente, fazendo com que i passe a ter o valor 0 (já que faz i = 3 - 3). A linha (4) então imprime o valor atual de i, que é 0.

Finalmente a execução retorna à linha (2), mas dessa vez o processamento não entra no laço pois a condição não é mais verdadeira.

Experimente executar esse código:

```
i = 6
while True:
  i = i - 3
  if(i > 0):
    print (i)
  else:
    break
```

Observe que nesse código a condição do laço é *de fato* sempre verdadeira (afinal, é fixo `True`), e a condição correta (a sua condição original) foi movida pra dentro do laço em um `if`. Analise com esse novo código como o computador processa linha a linha de forma sequencial, acompanhando o valor atual da variável em cada passo (esse procedimento costuma - ou costumava - se chamar ["teste de mesa"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lNCLHzTVIE)). Vai te ajudar a entender como a "lógica" influencia na resolução de problemas. :)

Answer (score 2):

> count < 10 é sempre true no ponto B.

Na verdade não é. No ponto B o count será o count anterior +1. Seu máximo será 9, pois o while pára se o count for igual a 10. Teste seu script.

```
i = 6
while (i > 0):
  i = i - 3;
  print (i)
```

**Primeiro**: A identação utilizada está fora das recomendações. Dentro de um loop, função, classe ou o que seja, o recomendado e comumente utilizado são 4 espaços. Isso é importante para manter uma padronização e uma boa organização visual do código, assim se demais pessoas forem utilizar o código, estarão familiarizados com a formatação.
**Segundo**: O ponto e vírgula é desnecessário.
**Terceiro e resposta da pergunta**: Pense como o script:
O `i`entra no loop como 6, se torna 3 e é impresso. O loop recomeça com o `i` como 3, se torna 0 e é impresso novamente. Só então que o `i` é testado novamente (dessa vez sendo 0) e não entra no loop.

Comment: Realmente, errei em dizer que está errado. Deveria ter dito que está fora das recomendações.